# Как перекодировать Windows-1252 в UTF-8?

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, iconv

Спарсил один заказ, записываю в базу. Если записывать в базу как есть, то в базе будет: **`ÐžÑ„Ð¾Ñ€Ð¼Ð»ÐµÐ½`**

Пробовал переводить этот текст в декодере выводит: **CP1252 → UTF-8** = **Оформлен**

В базу русский текст не записывается(нужно слово "Оформлен"), а пишутся каракули.

1) Пробую перекодировать:

```
$result=iconv('Windows-1252', 'utf8', "$text");
```

Результат тот же.
Вычитал в еще такой способ:

```
$res=iconv('Windows-1252', 'Windows-1251', "$text");
$res=iconv('Windows-1251', 'utf8', "$res");
return $res;
```

Результат пуст.

2) Пробую по-другому:

```
iconv('utf8', 'Windows-1251', "$text");
```

Результат: **Îôîðìëåí**
Смотрю что это за кодировка, результат:

> ```
> Как нам пришлось помучиться
> CP1252 → CP1251
> получилось слово: Оформлен
> ```
>
> То есть кодировка не меняется? Как сменить кодировку?

Comment: Вики сомневается, что это 1252 кодировка https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1#Windows.E2.88.921252 Делайте перевод так `$str = iconv('CP1251', 'UTF-8//IGNORE//TRANSLIT', $str);` <-- из Windows-1251 в UTF-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение проблемы в кодировке сервера MySQL. По-умолчанию latin1. Поменять нужно кодировку в файле:

> sudo nano -w /etc/mysql/my.cnf

Допишем в конец файла следующие строки:

```
skip-character-set-client-handshake
character-set-server = utf8
init-connect='SET NAMES utf8'
collation-server=utf8_general_ci
```

Вообще текст не нужно перекодировать. Так и записываем в базу как есть.

Comment: База тоже имеет свою кодировку, вы проверьте, у вас с большой долей вероятности база также имеет latin1 - и сервер постоянно выполняет переконвертации из одной кодировки в другую. Самое оптимальное - когда база и все клиенты подключаются в одной и той же кодировке. Литературы в сети много - ещё начиная с mysql 4, читайте внимательно -- вопрос важный.

Answer (score 2):

Это обычная 1251  а не 1252 -- очень часто все эти автоматические распознавалки путают эти две кодировки, при этом реально 1252 встречается намного реже.

Ваш вопрос нужно поделить на два вопроса. Сначала верно переконвертировать текст в правильную кодировку (iconv -- правильное решение, вы сами написали); второе -- верно вставить в базу данных. Вот тут уже нужно смотреть кодировку подключения/базы/сервера и может быть много ньюансов. Ведь вы же везде пишете "база", "в базу", верно?

Сначала посмотрите, чтобы выводилось правильно на страницу (файл, отладчик). Не забывайте, что страница с исходным кодом тоже может кодировку не uft-8, а cp1251. И при выводе на страницу важны заголовки, отдаваемые сервером и прописанные в хедерах.

Потом проверьте настройки подключения к базе. Иногда бывает можно set names utf8 поставить, если лень разбираться в вопросах кодировок.

Comment: да, проблема была в кодировке базы

Answer (score 0):

Для тех, кто столкнётся с такой же проблемой:

```
$str = 'Òêàíè Òåëà';
$str = iconv('utf-8', 'cp1252', $str);
$str = iconv('cp1251', 'utf-8', $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: `$ iconv -c -f utf-8 -t cp1252 text.txt | iconv -c -f cp1251 -t utf-8`